# Position not loaded with fill command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm getting the error message "That position is not loaded" and I have no idea why with this command:

```
/fill ~-467 ~69 ~-394 ~-394 ~92 ~-470 minecraft:air
```

I've tried making the coordinates above closer together - moving myself to the middle of the coordinates to make sure I'm in the chunk and that it's loaded. I've also made sure cheats are enabled. I've double checked that I haven't made any typos in what I want to clear... I'm really confused and have been Googling, so I really hope it's not something that simple/silly...

I'm in Java 1.19.2 - no resource packs/mods

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/c3z3pr/question_that_position_is_not_loaded_error_when/)!  The ~ indicates relative distance to your current location, so I needed to remove the ~'s from my command to have it work - FYI in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.